Get back the NULL date records between another set of dates
In MySQL 5.7, I have a table that looks like this:
| email  | a_last_sent | a_last_open | b_last_sent | b_last_open | ...more columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1 | 2024-06-12  | 2024-06-25  |  2024-03-06 | 2024-06-06  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email2 | 2024-06-01  | 2024-06-16  |  2024-06-05 |    NULL     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email3 | 2024-06-01  |   NULL      |  2024-05-12 | 2024-06-10  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email4 |   NULL      |   NULL      |  2024-04-02 | 2024-05-11  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email5 | 2024-06-09  | 2024-05-01  |    NULL     |    NULL     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am trying to return the last_open rows that are NULL that were last_sent 180 days (from June).
So the results need to have a last_sent date going back 180 days AND a NULL last_open date.
In the above example, there are some that have a NULL last_sent date AND a NULL last_open date - I don't need to return those records.
Just the last_sent going back 180 days (from June) AND NULL last_open.
Here is what I tried:
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 
 (`a_last_sent` BETWEEN '2024-01-02' AND '2024-06-30' AND `a_last_open` IS NULL)
 + (`b_last_sent` BETWEEN '2024-01-02' AND '2024-06-30') AND (`b_last_open` IS NULL)
 + (`c_last_sent` BETWEEN '2024-01-02' AND '2024-06-30') AND (`c_last_open` IS NULL)
 ...more columns

Using the above table example, I was hoping to get results like this:
| email  | a_last_sent | a_last_open | b_last_sent | b_last_open | ...more columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email2 | 2024-06-01  | 2024-06-16  |  2024-06-05 |    NULL     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email3 | 2024-06-01  |   NULL      |  2024-05-12 | 2024-06-10  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Since email2 and email3 have a last_sent date that falls within 180 days from June AND a NULL last_open date, these results would be what I'm looking for.
But using the above query, I am getting zero results. What can I try next?

Why are you using + instead of OR?

If any of the  otherlast_sent dates are NULL, the condition x_last_sent BETWEEN ... will be NULL, which causes the entire condition to be false.

I think using IFNULL(x_last_sent, '1900-01-01') BETWEEN ... would solve this. Just use an impossible date as the default with IFNULL.

This would also be easier if you normalized the schema. Instead of having a_last_open, b_last_open, etc. you should have a table with separate rows for a, b, etc. and a foreign key referencing this table.

@barmar - I changed + to OR and now I am getting results.  Trying your IFNULL suggestion now.

Just a note: MySQL 5.7 reached end of life a year ago, and there are no security patches or bug fixes. You should consider upgrading soon.

@TheImpaler Thank you.  I have already brought that up with my company.

S a m p l e     D a t a :



email
a_last_sent
a_last_open
b_last_sent
b_last_open




email1
2024-06-12
2024-06-25
2024-03-06
2024-06-06


email2
2024-06-01
2024-06-16
2024-06-05
null


email3
2024-06-01
null
2024-05-12
2024-06-10


email4
null
null
2024-04-02
2024-05-11


email5
2024-06-09
2024-05-01
null
null



Try it like here:
Select    tbl.*
From      tbl
Where     ( a_last_open Is Null And DATE_ADD(a_last_sent, INTERVAL 180 DAY ) >= CURRENT_DATE )
       OR
          ( b_last_open Is Null And DATE_ADD(b_last_sent, INTERVAL 180 DAY ) >= CURRENT_DATE )

R e s u l t :



email
a_last_sent
a_last_open
b_last_sent
b_last_open




email2
2024-06-01
2024-06-16
2024-06-05
null


email3
2024-06-01
null
2024-05-12
2024-06-10



fiddle
